# How do I get the map pattern to correctly return a list of squares from a function?

Tags: python, list, testcase

I'm supposed to use the map pattern to make a result list that squares the numbers in the input list.

```
def square_all(list1):
    list1 = []
    squared = map(lambda x: x**2, list1)
    return squared
```

I thought I understood the map pattern syntax but when I run my test cases for the function it continues to tell me that my function is returning an empty list and I don't know why.

```
import unittest
import map
import point

class TestCases(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        nums = [2,3,4]
        self.assertEqual(map.square_all(nums), [4,9,16])



if __name__ == '__main__':
   unittest.main()
```

Comment: Are you on Python 3? `map` doesn't return a list on Python 3.

Comment: the function's indentation is incorrect. Also you should remove `list1 = []`

Comment: Also, don't call your modules `map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are initializing `list1=[]`, remove this and it will work

```
def square_all(list1):
    squared = map(lambda x: x**2, list1)
    return squared
```

If you want to do this using for loop:

```
def square_all(list1):
    squared=[]
    for x in list1:
        squared.append(x**2)
    return squared
```

Comment: do you know how I could do this using a for loop?